# Change Domino Server User Authentication Algorithm

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

When treating a Domino Server as a web server, a form containing the Username and Password of a user can be posted to a URL with the ?Login command to perform user authentication.

By default, the authentication searches through the names.nsf database, searching for a user by the same username. If the usernames match, then the passwords are compared (the submitted password is hashed and compared with the stored one). If a match is found, then user authentication is successful.

My question is whether it is possible to customize the web authentication algorithm. For example, is it possible to re-program it to search a database other than names.nsf, perform different password hashing if you are using a different type of password encryption, etc.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to figure this out by reading the documentation? Whether Domino allows you to configure its authentication methods would be a software configuration question, not a programming question. *This* site is for programming (code) and programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, version control systems, etc) questions.

Comment: Actually, this should not be closed. Customizing Domino authenticaiton to the extent that he has asked for - i.e., different hashing, etc. - requires programming with the Notes C API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Domino has a built-in feature called [Directory Assistance](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_directoryassistance_c.dita) that you can use to configure it to use LDAP servers or other databases. And you can do anything you want using the DSAPI support in the [Notes C API Toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/capi/).